# Is a fibered product $X \times_S Y$ of two schemes over $S$ the categorical product of $X$ and $Y$ in the category of $S$-schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi_X:X \rightarrow S$ and $\pi_Y: Y \rightarrow S$ be morphisms of schemes.  Then we refer to the pairs $(X,\pi_X), (Y, \pi_Y)$ as schemes over $S$, and a morphism of schemes $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is referred to as an $S$-morphism from $(X,\pi_X)$ to $(Y, \pi_Y)$ if $\pi_Y \circ f = \pi_X$.  So we have a category of $S$-schemes.  In that case, is the fibered product $X \times_S Y$ the same thing as the product of $(X,\pi_X)$ and $(Y,\pi_Y)$ in the category of $S$-schemes?  Looking at the universal property, this seems to be the case, but I just wanted to check since I haven't seen any authors refer to $X \times_S Y$ in this way.

Comment: Yes. This is true more generally in any category with pullbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the fibered product is the product in the category of $S$-schemes, this follows from the universal properties of the fibered product.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29#Universal_property